# ORA-00904 for one INNER JOIN but not for another

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, ora-00904

for one particular query I've written up the ORA-00904 error has occurred

```
SELECT '103040698' as StudID, M.Title, R.SHORTDESC, C.COLOURNAME
FROM MOVIE0698 M
INNER JOIN RATING0698 R
ON M.SHORTDESC = R.SHORTDESC
INNER JOIN COLOURTYPE0698 C
ON M.COLOURNAME = C.COLOURNAME
ORDER BY Title ASC;
```

specfically for ON **M.**SHORTDESC = R.SHORTDESC

However, the previous query I had just written beforehand that used an INNER JOIN as well

```
SELECT '103040698' as StudID, A.FullName, M.Title, M.RelYear
FROM CASTING0698 C
INNER JOIN ACTOR0698 A
ON C.ActorNo = A.ActorNo
INNER JOIN MOVIE0698 M
ON C.MovieNo = M.MovieNo
ORDER BY RelYear DESC;
```

this query runs perfectly, so I'm just unclear what I've done wrong.

From what I remember INNER JOINs are written with the child table first then the parent table e.g. ON C.ActorNo = A.ActorNo but I could be wrong since I know some software will accept either way while others are sensitive to it.

for context, I'm using SQLJunior for my school work

here is the whole error

> ON M.shortdesc = R.shortdesc
>
> ```
> *
> ```
>
> Error at line 4: ORA-00904: "M"."SHORTDESC": invalid identifier

Comment: The order of the tables in a join doesn't matter.  You're just linking two tables; neither one is "parent" or "child".  I don't see anything wrong with this.  Have you checked for strange characters in the file, like tabs or other control characters?  Can you post the whole error?

Comment: @TimRoberts I just added the whole error message but I guess the issue is less of the query I've written up and more of the create table / insert data file?

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit thick but your query that runs perfectly doesn't feature any columns called SHORTDESC. Are you certain you have the columns spelled correctly and referenced in the correct tables? Does movies table M actually have a SHORTDESC?

Comment: Some early versions of oracle were sensitive to which way round the ON was written but that should be a thing of the 30 years ago past

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm pretty sure I have, in the create table section of my text file I have the names of the tables in uppercase but in the 'insert' section the name are either all lower case or with the begining of the name being uppercase e.g. shortdesc vs FullName

Answer (score 1):

In plain English the error message means "the MOVIES0698 table doesn't have a column called SHORTDESC"

Remember that Oracle column names are only case insensitive if they are not enclosed in quotes, or were quoted allcaps. If a column name is enclosed in quotes, and is not all uppercase, when it is created then it must forced more be referred to using quotes

```
SHORTDESC -- not case sensitive, you could write SELECT shortDesc 
"SHORTDESC" -- not case sensitive, because it's all caps anyway, can write SELECT shortdesc
"ShortDesc" -- case sens, must refer to this column using quotes forever more: SELECT "ShortDesc"... JOIN ON M."ShortDesc" etc
```

In summary, never enclosed oracle column names in quotes, for any reason. If you want to call a column something that is a reserved word, call it something else

If movies has no such column you have to join on a different column (SHORTDESC seems like it would be a text column, which probably makes for a poor join target anyway; is there no other column that is intended to relate movies and ratings better? Such as a "movieid" in the ratings table? It seems to me like one movie could have one or more ratings (some critics rate it high, others low, and you average the scores of many ratings..?)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong column names to join these tables together, i was writing it as

```
SELECT '103040698' as StudID, M.Title, R.SHORTDESC, C.COLOURNAME
FROM MOVIE0698 M
INNER JOIN RATING0698 R
ON M.SHORTDESC = R.SHORTDESC
INNER JOIN COLOURTYPE0698 C
ON M.COLOURNAME = C.COLOURNAME
ORDER BY Title ASC;
```

instead of

```
SELECT '103040698' as StudID, M.Title, R.SHORTDESC, C.COLOURNAME
FROM MOVIE0698 M
INNER JOIN RATING0698 R
ON M.ratingcode= R.ratingcode
INNER JOIN COLOURTYPE0698 C
ON M.colourcode= C.colourcode
ORDER BY Title ASC;
```

TL:DR
I had to use the proper foreign/primary key for INNER JOIN

Comment: This is why a [mre] obligatory in code questions. But anyway (as could clearly be expected)--This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please look at the fornatted version of your post before publishing.

Comment: Inner joins are not on keys, they are on conditions. Constraints need not hold, or be known, or be declared in order to query. Queries are determined by row membership conditions for base tables & desired results. Constraints are to tell the DBMS to disallow invalid DB states.